# Triggering a function with a dropdown - Functions and Scripts for Google Sheets

Tags: triggers, google-sheets

Thanks for the support so far.

I've had a look but available information seems a little different to what I'm looking for so I'd very much appreciate a few pointers.

Sheet I'm working on:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K8QhVKWSsvHTFKDHNv3ySb5bcaU9I7tczIZvIkegbw0/edit#gid=1778672780

**What I'd like to achieve:**
On the Sheet 'Pharma'
When B1 dropdown is set to 'Pharma', I want the table to display all data for Pharma industry.

I.e., When B1 = Pharma,   I want the function in A3 to run 
(=query({Sanshiro!A1:O; Suil!A1:O; Yujiro!A1:O;Josh!A1:O}, "select * where Col2 contains 'Pharma'",0))

Is there a way to do this with just functions or do I have to use a script such as onEdit?

e.g. something along the lines of

```
=if (B2 = 'Pharma', run =query({Sanshiro!A1:O; Suil!A1:O; Yujiro!A1:O;Josh!A1:O}, "select * where Col2 contains 'Pharma'",0)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your query in A3 to:

```
=query({Sanshiro!A1:O; Suil!A1:O; Yujiro!A1:O;Josh!A1:O}, "select * where Col2 contains '"&B1&"'",0)
```

See if that works for you ?

Comment: Wow. This works perfectly, and so simply too. 

I don't quite understand what the "&B1&" equates to but it perfectly achieves what I want to do..

Comment: am I able to combine formula, i.e. I want to do the same as above however including multiple columns too?



=query({Sanshiro!A1:O; Suil!A1:O; Yujiro!A1:O;Josh!A1:O}, "select * where Col2 OR Col5 contains '"&B1&"'",0)

Comment: yes, but you will have to write something like this then: =query({Sanshiro!A1:O; Suil!A1:O; Yujiro!A1:O;Josh!A1:O}, "select * where Col2 contains '"&B1&"' or Col5 contains '"&B1&"' ",0)